# Unit Test unexpected Assert Failure

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, razor-pages, entity-framework-core-2.1

I am doing a unit test for a delete :

```
[Fact]
 public async Task DeleteSupplierAsync_SupplierIsDeleted_WhenSupplierIsFound()
 {
     using (var db = new SulferFireDbContext(Utilities.TestingDbContextOptions()))
     {
         // Arrange
         var seedSuppliers = SulferFireDbContext.GetSeedingSuppliers();
         await db.AddRangeAsync(seedSuppliers);
         await db.SaveChangesAsync();
         var recId = 123;
         var expectedSuppliers = seedSuppliers.Where(supplier => supplier.ID != recId).ToList();
         // Act
         await db.DeleteSupplierAsync(recId);
         // Assert
         var actualSuppliers = await db.Suppliers.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
         Assert.Equal(expectedSuppliers, actualSuppliers);
     }
}
```

The problem is that `expectedSuppliers` and `actualSuppliers` seems to be equals, but the test fails. This appears after `Assert.Equals` when I debug:

[image: Exception]

Answer (score 2):

`Assert.Equal` uses the object's `.Equal` to compare the two objects. As `List<>` is a reference type this comparison will fail as you already experienced.

Use `CollectionAssert` instead to compare the two collection. I would suggest `AreEquivalent`

```
//...code removed for brevity

CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expectedSuppliers, actualSuppliers);
```